# Python logging. Different log files for the same project

Tags: python, logging

I would to log in different files. Currently, all my logs are writing on the same file.

I've two files:

- extract.py
- insert.py

The extract.py calls insert.py

In my extract.py:

```
import insert
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log/extract.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

In my insert.py:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log/insert.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

The problem is that every log are sent in insert.log. How can I send the log generate by extract.py in extract.log and log generate by insert.py in insert.log?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two loggers, each with its own file handler. At each file:

```
log= logging.getLogger(__name__)
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(__name__+'.log', mode="w")
log.addHandler(hdlr) 
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

then call logging functions in `log` instead of the `logging` module

```
log.debug("my message")
```

Generally speaking, the quality of python's documentation is extraordinary. The [advanced tutorial included in the `logging` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules) covers this and much more

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your extract.py only (this will work in python2.7+ and python3.2+):

```
import logging
import logging.config

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s '
                    '(%(asctime)s; %(filename)s:%(lineno)d)',
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'extract_rotate_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename' : 'extract.log',
            'encoding': 'utf8',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*2, # 2 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
        },
        'insert_rotate_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename' : 'insert.log',
            'encoding': 'utf8',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*2, # 2 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'extract': {  # <-- put here name of your logger in extract.py
            'handlers': ['extract_rotate_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'insert': {  # <-- put here name of your logger in insert.py
            'handlers': ['insert_rotate_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

But precise name of you loggers, look for `# <--` in code above.

[Here](http://www.lexev.org/en/2013/python-logging-every-day/) is post about python logging with more details and examples